# Magic mouse momentum scrolling on Windows 7 bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, scrolling, magic-mouse

I have my Magic Mouse and I've gotten it working with Windows 7. Left and right click works as well as scrolling.

Now I want *smooth/inertial scrolling as well as middle click*. Is it possible?

Also, is there a way to imitate the ability in OSX to scroll any window regardless of whether or not that window has focus?

Comment: Try http://ehiti.de/katmouse/!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the inertial scrolling could probably be implemented in the driver, but Apple hasn't done that and I'm not aware of any secondary drivers that could take the place of Apple's.  They may do it in the future, but Apple views the ability to run Windows as a "convenience" feature for switchers; they're in the business of driving people to OS X (and/or iOS)

The scrolling-without-focus thing is something that's buried deep within OS X, at the framework level, and there are certain apps that don't use Cocoa (or really break Cocoa) that don't have this behavior.  There is no common such framework embedded in Windows (you can say .NET is, but its not, really; its still built/managed/maintained as an entity separate to the OS itself, and not integral to basic functionality the way Cocoa is to OS X).  Even if there was a way to do it for some apps in Windows, the disparate nature of applications over there means that it probably wouldn't work consistently.